# Flask render new template from dynamic form

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, flask

I'm trying to create a flask app using material design lite where a user can add a bunch of chips to a list from a form, submit the form, and then render a new template using the items in the list. However, I'm having difficulties figuring out how to submit the values of the chips when clicking the submit button and sending it to my server.

Here's a simple Hello Names example:

**Flask App**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('hello.html')

@app.route('/names', methods=['POST','GET'])
def say_hello():
    names = request.json
    return render_template('names.html', names)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**hello.html**

```
 <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content" "mdl-grid">
      <form id="name_inputs">
        <div id="name-inputs" class="mdl-cell--4-offset mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
          <h4>Who do you want to say hello to?</h4>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield" id="name-div">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="name"/>
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Name</label>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" id="name-add">
            Add
          </button>
          <ul id='name-list' style="padding: 0;">
            <!-- Open list for name -->
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" id="submit">
            Say Hello
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </main>
```

**Chips jQuery**

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#name-add").click(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        if (name != '') {
          var names_chip = '<li id="name-chips" style="list-style:none;">' +
                                '<span class="mdl-chip mdl-chip--deletable">' +
                                    '<span class="mdl-chip__text" style="font-size:16px;">' + name + '</span>' +
                                    '<button type="button" class="mdl-chip__action"><i class="material-icons">cancel</i></button>' +
                                '</span>' +
                              '</li>';
          $("#name-list").append(names_chip);
          $('#name').val('');
        }
      });
   });

   $(document).on('click','.mdl-chip__action',function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
     });
  </script>
```

I've been looking into ajax but can't even get it set up where if I click the submit button that it renders the 'names.html' by calling '/names' URL.

Comment: Where is exactly your problem? Any stacktraces?

Comment: I'm not running into any actual errors, it's just a question of redirecting a user to a new route using ajax. I think I'm using ajax incorrectly tho, and I should be using it to return new data the same page the user is on. I ended up creating a new jquery function that just appends the chips as inputs when the user submits the form. A bit hacky but it works